# How can I use package party to do a regression tree?

Tags: r

When I try to do a regression tree on stock prices.

```
formula_1 <- log_price ~ at + age2 + lcash + ldebtEquity + salesAsset
stock_tree_1 <- ctree(formula_1, data=stock_data_1, 
controls=ctree_control(maxdepth = 4, minbucket = 1000))
```

it shows error as this.

```
Error in model@fit(data, ...) : 
  error code -4 from Lapack routine 'dgesdd'
```

I try to run the same code on windows computer, it shows the same error as my macbook.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.